# User Authentication Via SQL Table

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to implement some security into my application. I have a table called USER_AUTHORIZATION which contains a list of valid single sign on ID's of those who are to be using the application. The format is COMPANYNAME\111222333 and is stored in a field called UNAME. I'm trying to perform a check upon visiting the application which see's if the current logged in user is in the valid users table. If their SSO is not in the table, I want to display an error message.

View

```
@model IEnumerable<BillingApp.Models.HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE>
@using System.Data;
@using System.Data.SqlClient;
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Table 8: Holiday Date Table";
Layout = "../Shared/Layout2.cshtml";
var whoareyoupeople = @User.Identity.Name;
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
string myerrorstring = "User " + whoareyoupeople + " attempted unauthorized access on " + date + ".";

string connStringswag = "Data Source=SWDB10DSQL;Initial Catalog=BillingUI;Integrated     Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework";
using (SqlConnection _connyswagyolo = new SqlConnection(connStringswag))
{
   _connyswagyolo.Open();
   string checkauth = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_AUTHORIZATION WHERE UNAME == " + whoareyoupeople + ")";
   SqlCommand Command223 = new SqlCommand(checkauth, _connyswagyolo);
   Command223.ExecuteNonQuery();
   _connyswagyolo.Close();
}

@section featured2 {
@if (whoareyoupeople not found in table){
    <center><h2 style="color:red">Access Denied for user @User.Identity.Name. You are not authorized to view this application.</h2></center>
    string fileName = "C:\\BillingExport\\SECURITY\\seclog.txt";
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)){
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(myerrorstring);
    }
}
}
else{
  //actual content to be displayed (table information) goes here
```

My two biggest issues are, how do i form the if statement to check the result of the query? Additionally, I receive the error "CS1513: } expected".

You'll notice the following section of code has a missing closing breacket in the using sqlconnection line. This is because for whatever reason, the first closing bracket is always recognized by visual studio 2012 as being the end of the code block (i.e; @{     } ).

**Update:** I moved the code to my controller

```
 public ActionResult HolidayDateTable()
    {
        var whoareyoupeople = User.Identity.Name;
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        string myerrorstring = "User " + whoareyoupeople + " attempted unauthorized access on " + date + ".";

        string connStringswag = "Data Source=SWDB10DSQL;Initial Catalog=BillingUI;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework";
        using (SqlConnection _connyswagyolo = new SqlConnection(connStringswag))
        {
            _connyswagyolo.Open();
            string checkauth = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_AUTHORIZATION WHERE UNAME == " + whoareyoupeople + ")";
            SqlCommand Command223 = new SqlCommand(checkauth, _connyswagyolo);
            int count = (int)Command223.ExecuteScalar();
            _connyswagyolo.Close();

            if (count == 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied");
            }
            else
            {
                return View(db.HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Currently receiving the error "Incorrect syntax near '='."
pointing to line int count = (int)Command223.ExecuteScalar();

**Update 2:** I have played around with my code, but no matter what I do, the proposed solution
     int count = (int)Command223.ExecuteScalar();
does not seem to work. Below is my updated controller code.

```
 public ActionResult HolidayDateTable()
    {
        var whoareyoupeople = User.Identity.Name;
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        string myerrorstring = "User " + whoareyoupeople + " attempted unauthorized access on " + date + ".";
        string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_AUTHORIZATION WHERE UNAME == " + whoareyoupeople + ")";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SWDB10DSQL;Initial Catalog=BillingUI;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        {
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_AUTHORIZATION WHERE UNAME == " + whoareyoupeople + ")");
            int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            if (count == 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied");
            }
            else
            {
                return View(db.HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE);
            }
        }
        }
```

**Update 3:** The issue was with my Query string rather than the C# code. I had to remove an equals sign. Now the issue I'm having is

```
Incorrect syntax near '\601011308'.
```

pointing to int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

This is a partial entry of a value in the tables UNAME field. It's missing the COMPANYNAME in front of it (i.e; COMPANYNAME\601011308). I thought count was supposed to return the amount of matches the SSO has with the database (i.e; if the logged in users SSO is 601011308, and that is a valid user for the application which is stored in the table, count should return 1).

Latest controller code for which I have the above problem in Update 3:

```
 public ActionResult HolidayDateTable()
    {
        var whoareyoupeople = User.Identity.Name;
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        string myerrorstring = "User " + whoareyoupeople + " attempted unauthorized access on " + date + ".";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SWDB10DSQL;Initial Catalog=BillingUI;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        {
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AUTHORIZED_USERS WHERE UNAME = " + whoareyoupeople + ")");
            int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            if (count == 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied");
            }
            else
            {
                return View(db.HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE);
            }
        }
        }
```

Comment: don't call  your database from the view, do it in the controller. You shouldn't have complex logic in your views.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC? If so, then this logic does not belong in your view. It belongs in the controller, and possibly in an action filter.

Comment: You want to build it from the ground up instead of relying on something built in? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/eeyk640h(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ExecuteNonQuery()`, use `ExecuteScalar()` since `Count()` will naturally return an integer.

`int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();` is actually what I just implemented yesterday. Then you just use count in your `else/if` statement.

Comment: Why use the _ for your connection?